# Could not update html form after serialization and submission with ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am posting a serialized form (actually the issue is with an array which is a part of the form) with ajax. After server has successfully processed my request it returns back partial view (html) with updated values and here everything seems good. But on frontend I receive partially updated html - old values in the existing inputs remain the same (as they were in serialized version) and new items are added (if any). If I remove serialization it works good.

Here is my ajax call:

```
    var form = $('#rentPayments');

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("RecalculateRentPayments", "OwnerArea")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            form.replaceWith(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            var exception = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(exception.Message);
        }
    });
```

And here is what I have on the server:

```
var rentPayments = _rentPaymentsService.RecalculatePayments(dto);
return PartialView("RentPayments", rentPayments);
```

How can I achieve receiving html with fully updated values? Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like this is an issue with the values received on the server and processed through your DTO. Can you describe what methods you've used to debug this - for example have you checked the content of the request to ensure the correct values are being sent? Do you have any caching on the response, either server or client side?

Comment: I did debug it in a simple way: checked the values after processing (here all seems good) and debugged the values passed to view while it was populating (here I had correct values as well) and then in browser debugger I see partially updated view. No, we don`t have caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the issue lied in model state which remained the same because I considered method as POST/PUT and ASP.NET didn`t update existing values on the partial view I passed to frontend, but only added or removed items from it.

Solution is to use **ModelState.Clear()** before passing model to view to completely update values on the view. [[link to source]](https://adevelopersnotes.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/in-asp-net-mvc-what-is-modelstate-clear/#:%7E:text=of%20the%20ModelState.%E2%80%9D-,ModelState.,the%20model%20to%20your%20View.)